# Integrating an odd function using symmetry

Tags: real-analysis, integration, symmetry, surface-integrals

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ which is odd in one variable. If $f(x,y,z)$ is odd in $x$, for example and without loss of generality, then $f(x,y,z)=-f(-x,y,z)$.

Consider the integral of  $f$ over a spherical surface $S$ centered at the origin with arbitrary radius, i.e,
$$
\iint_S f(x,y,z)\,dS.
$$
How do I show, by symmetry, that the integral is $0$?

**My attempt:** Since $f$ is odd, and considering the change of variables $t=-x$, thus $dx=-dt$, we have that
$$
I=\iint_S f(x,y,z)\,dS=-\iint_S f(-x,y,z)\,dS=-\iint_S \left(-f(t,y,z)\right)\,dS.
$$
Then, using the fact that $f$ is odd, again, we get
$$
-\iint_S \left(-f(t,y,z)\right)\,dS\equiv -\iint_S f(x,y,z)\,dS=-I.
$$
Thus, the only solution to $I=-I$ is $I=0$. Is this correct? Is this change of variables what is meant by 'symmetry'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider the two hemispheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ separeted by $y-z$ plane then

$$I=\iint_S f(x,y,z)\,dS=\iint_{S_1} f(x,y,z)\,dS+\iint_{S_2} f(x,y,z)\,dS$$

and by $t=-x$

$$\iint_{S_2} f(x,y,z)\,dS=\iint_{S_1} f(-t,y,z)\,dS=-\iint_{S_1} f(t,y,z)\,dS$$